# Vaadin-combo-box sorting

Tags: sorting, firebase, polymer, vaadin

I'm trying to sort an array of objects in alphabetic order. However, somehow the `vaadin-combo-box` Polymer element only shows the first item in the array after a sort (even though there are more items in the array)

[image]

[image]

I'm getting my data from Firebase (called `settingsData`) so I have to use a splices observer to see if data is being added or remove:

**Observer**

```
observers: [
  'sortData(settingsData.splices)'
],



sortData: function(newD, oldD) {
   if(newD) {
       var tmp = this.settingsData.sort(function(a,b) {return (a.name.toUpperCase() > b.name.toUpperCase()) ? 1 : ((b.name.toUpperCase() > a.name.toUpperCase()) ? -1 : 0);} );
       //tmp is an array in the correct order
       this.set("filteredItems", tmp);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <vaadin-combo-box id="picker" label="[[label]]"  items="[[filteredItems]]"  item-label-path="name" item-value-path="name" value="{{valueText}}" on-value-changed="valueChanged"></vaadin-combo-box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the observer for array mutations is not fired after the first time. This means that the view for the `vaadin-combo-box` is not rendered correctly, which seems a little bit odd?

Clearing the array every time I'm trying to set the new data did the trick.

```
 this.set("filteredItems", []);
 this.set("filteredItems", tmp);
```

Comment: This is actually a Polymer best-practice; it forces the DOM to update. :)

Answer (score 0):

Either `this.settingsData.sort` really returns only 1 item or Firebase's Reactive data breaks it. Unable to reproduce it with inline array data.